# Missing refresh bar when looking at specific tag

Tags: bug, stack-overflow, live-refresh, new-questions

I have noticed that on StackOverflow, I have the newest questions tagged 'android' open and it never seems to say "# questions with new activity" as it did yesterday (I think I first noticed this last night on Mac with Chrome (27?). If I refresh the page there are a number of questions that were newly posted, so it is not as if there is no activity. I am currently on a Windows 7 machine with IE 10.

What has happened to the "# questions with new activity"?

Comment: web sockets server is down, hopefully the team will bring it back sooner than later.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Thanks, I didn't see that when I was looking for dups.

Comment: ...and it's back to life!

Comment: YAY! I can prolong getting carpal tunnel just a little longer by no longer needed to reach for F5 again!